# Hot Towel SPA Modal Dialog knockout bindings and validation

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I'm building a SPA using the Hot Towel SPA template.
Here's my problem:
I have a view where I put the information related to a Venue (Name, Description, Address, etc.)
Associated with the Venue there are different Rooms with their own fields (Name, Description, Type, etc.)
I have a list of Rooms and a button "Add New Room".
When I hit the button, a modal dialog pops up, I fill the form with the requested information then I save. After the dialog is closed the list gets updated.
I am able to retrieve the information from the dialog, but I'm not able to trigger the validation rules if the fields are left blank.
 Also the **datacontext.HasChanges()** returns always true.
Is it possible to use the modal dialog like any other view?
Here's part of the code I am using:
From **Model.cs**:

```
public class Venue
{
    [Key]
    public int VenueId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Venue Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Venue Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Fields { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int VenueId { get; set; }
    public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

From **venuedetail.js**:

```
define(['services/datacontext',
    'services/model',
    'durandal/plugins/router',
    'durandal/system',
    'durandal/app',
    'services/logger',
    'viewmodels/roommodal'],
function (datacontext, model, router, system, app, logger, roommodal) {
    ...
    var addRoom = function () {
        var newRoom= datacontext.manager.createEntity("Room");
        roommodal.room = newRoom;
        app.showModal(roommodal).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {

            }
            return true;
        });
    };
    ...
```

From roommodal.js:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'durandal/system',     'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
function (app, datacontext, system, router, logger) {
    var isSaving = ko.observable(false);
    var room= ko.observable();
    activate = function(routeData) {
        return true;
    };
hasChanges = ko.computed(function() {
    return datacontext.hasChanges(); // Always true ?
});
canSave = ko.computed(function() {
    return hasChanges() && !isSaving();
});

canDeactivate = function () {
    return true;
};

var save = function(dialogResult) {
    this.modal.close(dialogResult);
    };

    var cancel = function() {
        this.modal.close(false);
    };

var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    save: save,
    canSave: canSave,
    cancel: cancel,
    canDeactivate: canDeactivate,
    room: room,
    hasChanges: hasChanges,
    title: 'Add room'
};

return vm;
```

From **roommodal.html**:

```
<div class="messageBox">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
    <i class="icon-asterisk" data-bind="visible: hasChanges"></i>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div data-bind="with: room">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
            placeholder="Enter name" />
        <div>
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea data-bind="value: description"
                placeholder="Enter description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Notes</label>
            <textarea data-bind="value: notes"
                placeholder="Enter notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-info"
        data-bind="click: cancel, enable: canSave">
        <i class="icon-undo"></i>Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info"
        data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave">
        <i class="icon-save"></i>Save</button>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is triggered when you try to save using `datacontext.saveChanges()` which you don't do in this piece of code, instead, you are just closing the modal window.

Easiest way to see if saving was successful is to check `HasChanges` afterwards - it should be false if everything went well, otherwise it will be true.

`datacontext.HasChanges()` returns true when you enter modal window because you create an entity and place it in your context before opening the modal window. You can only ignore `HasChanges` and silently `CancelChanges` before closing the modal window.